# copy file without modify permission on windows

Tags: windows, permissions, vb6, filesystems, file-copying

I want to have my software copy a file from a source to a destination. In the destination folder though i don't have modify-permissions.

I've created a group and only gave

- Read & execute
- List folder contents
- Read
- Write

as permissions and added my user to the group.

Now, when i execute my code i get a "permission denied" as a result.

I've tried copying the file using a FileSystemObject.CopyFile and using LZCopy which gave me a LZERROR_BADOUTHANDLE.

```
fso.CopyFile source, destination, True
```

and

```
hDest = LZOpenFile(destination, DestStruct, OF_CREATE)

'Copy the files
lResults = LZCopy(hSource, hDest)
```

From what i read here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc982153.aspx=) the write permission should be enough to create a file and write data into it. Why doesn't copy work?

More important : is there another way for me to make the file appear in the destination folder?

Comment: Did you remember to log out and back in after adding the user to the group?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the file permission or the user permission that is causing the problem. To tell which, try adding full permission to the folder and see if the program runs. Then try running the compiled .exe file as an Administrator (In Windows Explorer right click, run as administrator). If it's the folder permissions, you can either adjust the permissions or see what the application is doing to cause the problem. If it's the user permissions, you may need to run the application as a different user or change user permissions.

Comment: It's sufficient to add the "Modify" permission to get the thing working. But that is exactly what we're trying to avoid. Users should not be able to modify files once they've been copied into this folder.